# Featured images get shrunken

Tags: media-library, images

While uploading featured images, the problem I am getting is, all images are shrinking automatically.

I want to retain the original image. Check [this example](http://calebschools.com/cicmjs/designations/class-teacher/page/4/). All staff memebers images are shrinked automatically but in featured images I have uploaded a full image of staff members.

I thought that images are too large so that  wordpress is automatically shrinking the images, so, I have scaled and cropped the images in media library. Some of the images got fix but some remains the problem.

Is there a way that the orignial uploaded image will be shown as it is?

Comment: If you want your theme to show full size image then you will have to change `thumbnail` size in theme file. Search which theme file this page uses and replace thumbnail id with `full`.

Comment: @Roberthue in upload folder there are various copies of same image present with different size. wordpress is picking the image with 242x180 size..how to change this?

Comment: All different image sizes generated in upload folder are defined in `functions.php` file but to use different image thumbnail in website, you will have to change in theme file. Search which theme file this page uses and replace thumbnail id with `full` or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey if you want to add custom image size then add the following code in your function.php file

```
add_image_size( 'thumb', 220, 180, true );
```

and then call featured image in your template like this

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
    the_post_thumbnail('thumb');
} 
?>
```

i think it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in upload folder there are various copies of same image present with different size. wordpress is picking the image with 242x180 size..how to change this?

Comment: By default when upload any image by using media uploader in WordPress it create three different size like thumbnail(default 150px x 150px max), medium(default 300px x 300px max), large(default 640px x 640px max) and full is original image size.

Comment: if you want to access custom size then follow above code

Comment: Where to add second part of your code?

Comment: second part of code add in your template file like content.php or in your custom template where you echo the post content like the_content

Comment: Sorry to bother you..but when i add add_image_size it says call to undefined function..but adding second part of your code shows the thumbnail on page but with smaller size..

Comment: have a look at http://calebschools.com/cicmjs/designations/class-teacher/page/4/

Comment: Hey add_image_size() function add within your `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'function_name' );` where your function_name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19667/discussion-between-james-and-amitrh).